# How to set the height of div dependent on number of child divs inside the parent div

Tags: css, html, height

On this page **bonusnavigator.ru**

I have a div:`.toppanel` `.topcasino` `.inner`

It's now showing 11 subdivs - `.toppanel` `.topcasino` `.inner` `.row`- (deals). When I try to reduce the number of deals, I get this:

http://screencast.com/t/eajlX3xNTm2

How can I set up the css so that child divs fill up the freed up space like this:

http://screencast.com/t/vKlPct3Avb4V

Thank you all in advance.

**UPDATE**: Thanks to the first two suggestions but they deal with "post result". What I was asking about is how do I set up children divs (deals) to change heights dynamically to fill up freed space depending on how many deals there are in the parent div.

Comment: It seems I got the wrong. Please post your CSS, HTML here.

Comment: is the child divs count dynamic?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't played with your CSS, but are you using jquery? If so, you can set the height based on the number of deals using height() function.

You can get the height of the container div using $(".inner").height();

Then divide the height by number of DIVs inside it and set the height of all the child Divs to that value. Something like this (syntax might be incorrect, because I just typed out the code here):

```
var containerHeight = $(".inner").height();
var divCount = $(".inner > div").length; /* returns the number of DIVs which are direct children of the parent */
var divHeight = Math.Round(containerHeight/divCount); /* number being the count of your divs */
$(".inner > div").height(divHeight);
```

Comment: there is no `jquery` or `js` tag in the question....this is otherwise *an answer*

Comment: Sure, but I will just leave it here if someone is looking for a jquery answer!

Comment: Thanks guys! ;) I am still playing around with the css only version but will consider javascript solution too if needed.

Answer (score 1):

**PURE CSS WAY**

you can use `display:table;` for this

[**see demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/6WDj7/)

Just set the child divs to  :

`display:table-row;`

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
#parent {
    /* height:100%;*/ /*can be dynamic too*/
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #F00;
    display:table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    height:300px;
}
.child {
    width:100%;
    display:table-row;
    border:1px solid #000;
    height:100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child">This is a child 1</div>
    <div class="child">This is a child 2</div>
    <div class="child">This is a child 3</div>
    <div class="child">This is a child 4</div>
    <div class="child">This is a child 5</div>
    <div class="child">This is a child 6</div>
    <div class="child">This is a child 7</div>
    <div class="child">This is a child 8</div>
    <div class="child">This is a child 9</div>
    <div class="child">This is a child 10</div>
    <div class="child">This is a child 11</div>
    <div class="child">This is a child 12</div>
    <div class="child">This is a child 13</div>
    <div class="child">This is a child 14</div>
    <div class="child">This is a child 15</div>
    <div class="child">This is a child 16</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked like a charm!!! Awesome! The only last concern is that the borders in the child divs stopped working - http://screencast.com/t/VhGfmtiHV Is there a way to use this method and keep the borders incact?

Comment: given: `width:100%` and `1px` border...this makes `width:100%+2px` **> 100%**....which is making it overflow.....just play around with the width to suit your need and you'll see the margins!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use fixed height. Use `height: auto;` and `overflow: hidden;` to wrap the container. if this does not work paste here your HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try replace line `padding: 2px 0 4px;` from `.toppanel .topcasino .inner .row` classes with `padding: 2px 0 26px`. That should do the trick.